# My function in html isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made a function to calculate average and tried to use this function in each section. But the calculation isn't working properly. If you see the code below, the handleCalculateAverageButtonClick('Question1') function works in  first section (section class = "Question1") but the handleCalculateAverageButtonClick('Question2')  function's calculation is wrong in the second section (second class="Question2"). Is there something to modify in my code?

html code

```
             <section class = "Question1">
            how many times do you want to buy on scale? 
              <input type = "number" style = "height : 20px ; width: 50px; " class = "scale-count" /> 
            
            <button type = "button"  onclick = "handleNextButtonClick('Question1')" style = "padding 
            : 4px 19px;">
            Next
            </button>
            
            <div class = "form-output"> </div>
            <br>
            <button class = "button button1" onclick = 
            "handleCalculateAverageButtonClick('Question1')">
            CalculateAverage
            </button> &nbsp; : 
             &nbsp; <span class= "average1"></span>
           </section>

             
           <section class = "Question2">
              How many times do you want to sell on scale?
              <input type = "number" style ="height : 20px; width: 50px;" class = "scale-count" />
              <button type = "button" onclick = "handleNextButtonClick('Question2')" style = 
               "padding:4px 19px;">
                Next
              </button>
              <div class = "form-output"></div>
              <br>
              <button class = "button button1" onclick = 
               "handleCalculateAverageButtonClick('Question2')">
                CalculateAverage
                </button> &nbsp; :
                &nbsp; <span class = "average1"></span>
              
          </section>
```

javascript code

```
          function getNumberOfScales(){
            const temp = parseInt(document.querySelector("." + parent + " .scale-count").value);
            const numberOfScales = isNaN(temp) || temp<0 ? 0 : temp;
           return numberOfScales; 
           }

           
           function rowGenerator(index){
           return `
           <div class = "row" data-index = "${index}">
           &nbsp &nbsp  Price ${index} : &nbsp <input class = "price" style = "height : 30px ; width: 
           50px;"  
           data-index = "${index}" type = "number" /> &nbsp Count : &nbsp
           <input class = "count" style = "height : 30px ; width: 50px;" data-index = "${index}" type 
            = "number" />
            </div> `; 
            }

           function handleNextButtonClick(parent){
    
           const numberOfScales = getNumberOfScales(parent);
           const formOutput = document.querySelector("."+parent+" .form-output");
           let stringBuffer = " ";
          for (let index=1; index<= numberOfScales; index++){
           stringBuffer += rowGenerator(index);
           }
          formOutput.innerHTML = stringBuffer;
           }  

    
     function getAverage(parent){

    let sum = 0 ; 
    let sum_count = 0;
    const numberOfScales = getNumberOfScales(parent);
    for (let index = 1; index <= numberOfScales; index++){
        const row_price = document.querySelector(`input.price[data-index = '${index}']`).value  ;
        const row_count = document.querySelector(`input.count[data-index = '${index}']`).value  ;
        sum += row_price * row_count;
        sum_count += parseInt(row_count); 
    }
    console.table({
        sum,
        sum_count
    })
    if (sum_count ==0 ){
        return 0;
    } else{
        return sum/sum_count ; 
    }
}

      

    function handleCalculateAverageButtonClick(parent) {
    const average = getAverage(parent);
    const avg1 = document.querySelector("." + parent +" .average1");
    avg1.innerHTML = average;
    
}
```

Comment: `getNumberOfScales` does not accept a `parent` parameter...

Comment: oh it's originally getNumberOfScales(parent) , i misspelled it here.  Anyway  handleCalculateAverageButtonClick(parent) function isn't working properly in section2 which means the calculation is wrong. Could you help me please?